# How to navigate through elements using find or find_all instead of select?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

As I know, you can navigate through page's elements with select method e.g.:

```
text = soup.select('.css-lw5dil > .css-1p6sxhz')
```

Is there any way to do so with find method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select_one` is equal to `find` and select is equal to `find_all or findAll`
select_one /find for single element and select/find_all for a `list`
Yes, you can navigate that but  css selector's locator is more flexible in this case.

```
text = soup.select('.css-lw5dil > .css-1p6sxhz')
```

Using soup locator as follows:

```
text = soup.find('tag name',class_="css-lw5dil").find_all('tag name',class_= "css-1p6sxhz")
```

Now you can iterate over it like css selector as follows:

```
for i in text:
    do something new
```